# Creating a histogram chart for each category

Tags: dc.js

I am trying to create histogram having `ages` in groups like this `(0-10), (10-20), ...(90,100)`

Dataset look like this:

```
0: {agebracket: "20", currentstatus: "Recovered", dateannounced: "30/01/2020"}
1: {agebracket: "45", currentstatus: "Confirmed", dateannounced: "02/03/2020"}
2: {agebracket: "24", currentstatus: "Recovered", dateannounced: "02/03/2020"}
.
.
.
99: {agebracket: "58", currentstatus: "Hospitalized", dateannounced: "20/03/2020"}
```

I was able to create histogram but that was on the whole dataset. I didn't take account of

```
"currentstatus" --> "Recovered", "Hospitalized", "Deceased"
```

**On whole dataset:**

[image]

I tried to create histogram by currentstatus but it look like this:
[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
var binwidth = 10;
var dim = cf.dimension(function(d) { 
    return parseInt(d.agebracket); });

var age_by_cases= dim.group().reduce(
// add
    (p, v) => {

      p[v.currentstatus] = (p[v.currentstatus] || 0) + 1;
      return p;
    },
// remove
    (p, v) => {
      p[v.currentstatus] -= 1;
      return p;
},
// init
    () => ({})
);
```

---

```
barChart
    .height(300)
    .width(500) //give it a width
    .dimension(dim)
    .group(age_by_cases, type)
    .elasticY(true)
    .valueAccessor(function(p) { 
        return p.value[type_c];
        // return (binwidth * Math.floor(parseInt(p.value[type_c])/binwidth)) ; 
        })  
    .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([1,101]))
    .xUnits(dc.units.fp.precision(binwidth))

    .elasticX(true);
```

**Line no. 170-184** and **Line no. 227-243**
https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/8e2c0b407fdb1991c9cc5e81e447ebe2

I just got struck at this badly. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Please include the rest of the relevant crossfilter code in your question. It looks like you need to bin by the binwidth as you have commented out in the valueAccessor, but this isn’t the right place - it should usually be in your dimension definition.

Comment: @Gordon: I have updated the post. Thanks gordon that actually helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you will define the binning in the dimension key function:

```
var dim = cf.dimension(function(d) { 
    return binwidth * Math.floor(parseInt(p.agebracket)/binwidth);
};
```

And then, use the bin width (or other binning spec) in `xUnits`, as you have it:

```
.xUnits(dc.units.fp.precision(binwidth))
```

This causes crossfilter to sort each row into the bin with the value rounded down by `binwidth`, and it tells dc.js to calculate the bar width also using the binwidth.